# passing parameter to javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with getting parameter from javascript onClick function

```
title = "as"
$('<li onClick=pushRight('+hello+') class="item"></li>')
```

and my console log print this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Why don't you set-up a `jQuery` event handler for that element instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
title = "as"
$('<li onClick="pushRight("'+hello+'")" class="item"></li>')
```

See the added double quotes. `"'+hello+'"` Also double quotes over your `pushRight` function.

Your code won't work because it render an invalid html as shown below.

```
<li onClick=pushRight(as) class="item"></li>
```

> See, there were no quotes before and after pushRight, also before and after your
>   string `"sa"`. Know the mistake and correct. Using inline js with html is not recommended.You have to bind events in these scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use inline js (onlick in your html).

See reasons not to use inline js here:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Here's a proper way with jQuery:

```
var $myElem = $('<li class="item"></li>');
$myElem.click(function() {
  pushRight('hello');
});
```

And it's quite easy even without jQuery:

```
var myElem = document.createElement('li');
myElem.className = 'item';
myElem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pushRight('hello');
});
```

Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/uDURojOY/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
hello = 'anything';
$('<li onClick=pushRight("'+hello+'") class="item"></li>')
```